# Link between fundamental theorem of calculus and integral with parameters

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

My problem is the following :

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. We know that
$$F:x\mapsto\int_0^xf(t)dt$$ is the primitive of $f$ that vanishes in $0.$ But i can rewrite $F$ as $$F:x\mapsto\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t)\,f(t)dt=\int_\mathbb{R}g(x,t)dt$$ with $g(x,t)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t)\,f(t).$ Here, if I want to apply the theorem of differentiation of integrals with parameters, I encounter some problems. For example, if I take $f\equiv 1$ the constant function, then for a fixed $t\in\mathbb{R},$ $g(\cdot,t):x\mapsto g(x,t)=\mathbb{1}_{[t,+\infty]}(x)$ is not differentiable - not continuous.

My question is : did I do something wrong or is this just showing that this is a case where the theorem of differentiation of integrals with parameters can't be applied ? Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Your calculation of $g$ when $f=1$ doesn't make any sense.  How did you get that?

Comment: Just writing $g(x,t)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t)=\mathbb{1}_{[t,+\infty]}(x).$

Comment: The fact that you can't interchange the integral and derivative isn't surprising when the integrand isn't even continuous with respect to the variable of differentiation.

Comment: @Dr.MV : yes it seems logical indeed ! Perhaps it will take sense in test function space, I'm waiting for the answer of leonbloy.

Answer (score 1):

Considered as a function of $x$, (for a fixed $t>0$), $$g(x,t)=\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t) f(t)$$ is a step function. Its value is zero for $x<t$ and jumps to $f(t)$ for $x\ge t$. Hence, it's derivative is zero everywhere  except on $x=t$, where there is a discontinuity (jump of size $f(t)$). Hence, you are right, the function is not differentiable, and you cannot derivate inside the integral.

If you know about Dirac deltas, though, and you are not rigorous, you could write

$$ \frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial x}= f(t)\delta(x-t)$$
and hence applying  the rule you'd get

$$\frac{dF}{dx}=\int f(t)\delta(x-t) dx =f(x)$$
which is, of course, the desired result. But, again, this is not rigorous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I have to talk about Schwartz's distributions if I want to gain a degree in generalisation ?